# Selenium code doesn't terminate

Tags: python, selenium

The following code won't terminate. What could be the reason for that?

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://www.quora.com/physics")
elem = driver.find_element_by_class_name("cancel")

#ele=elem[0]

print "done"
```

Comment: The problem probably is that the element is in http://www.quora.com/physics# while i try to search it in http://www.quora.com/physics. But i am not able to find any alternative. Any suggestions/explanations?

Comment: What is the last action that selenium does before stopping to respond?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Using linkText instead of className. It is working when i tried.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://www.quora.com/physics")
elem = driver.find_element_by_link_text("Close & Read Quora")

print "done"
```

Comment: This worked for me too, it just takes a very long time, like a few minutes, to find the element for some reason