# Timeout error while using watir webdriver with Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, selenium, selenium-webdriver, watir, watir-webdriver

I am new to watir webdriver with ruby and I am trying out a few examples. I am getting a timeout error "Net::ReadTimeout: Net::ReadTimeout" for the following code -

```
b = Watir::Browser.new
b.goto "http://www.quora.com"
b.text_field(:name => 'email').set 'someone@gmail.com'
b.text_field(:name => 'password').set 'somepassword'
b.button(:class => 'submit_button').click
```

When I run the above code in console, firefox gets launched and quora main page comes up. But after that it doesn't do anything until it times out. I inspected the elements for username and password and they are right.

I ran the same code for gmail.com with the corresponding fields and it runs just fine.

Can someone please help?

Ameya

Answer (score 2):

This is a known issue with quora.com.

Currently I'm not aware of any solutions, one possibility is to disable JavaScript when you login, but in this case you can't do much else after login. Maybe you can create a ticket in Selenium issue tracker.

See similar questions asked before.

- [Selenium code doesn't terminate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16579699/1177636)
- [Why am I not able to login to Quora using an automation package like Selenium or Watir?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21687214/1177636)
- [How to add JS on a page when it has been turned off initially by Selenium?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21709212/1177636)
- [Is Selenium slow, or is my code wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17462884/1177636)

Comment: It's interesting that I could get the same example to work in java using selenium, but not in ruby. Not sure what's the reason.

Comment: @amey1908: Ha, interestingly, I saw this issue acorss Ruby, Python and C#, but I never had chance to play with Java.